# Create a custom relationship @IBOutlet like UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, iboutlet

I think there is no way to do it, but i was wondering if it is possible to create the `@IBOutlet` somehow that would work as a relationship one, kind of like you can connect a bunch of viewControllers to `UITabBarController`

I tried adding

```
@IBOutlet var controllers: [UIViewController]?
```

to my VC, but, unsurprisingly, IB won't let me connect this outlet to VCs in other scenes.

Note: i am not looking for workarounds, i know i can use `storyboard?.instantiateViewController()` and such, this is what i am doing. But being able to click-n-drag is kind of cool, and this is really why i want to try to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that's possible to have 1 outlet presenting a list of UIViewControllers, However, you have the option to get the similar behaviour with your code:

```
var registeredControllers:[UIViewController] = []
// Base Class
class RegisterableViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        registeredControllers.append(self)
    }
}
// Used in your UI Code
class ViewController1:RegisterableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Initialize UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Mate, this is great. Like it said in the original question, `i am not looking for workarounds`. Specifically, i know i can do this with code. I want to know how to do it with drag-n-drop because (again original question): `being able to click-n-drag is kind of cool, and this is really why i want to try to do that`